# Submit button is not working after using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I created a login page that has a login form which submits username and password to loginproc.php in order to check their validity and everything was working perfectly. Anyway, on the login page I wrote a JavaScript function that alert the user in case the username and password fields are empty. After I've done that, the JavaScript works fine but when i click the submit button nothing happens absolutely!

----------------------------------------This is the JavaScript----------------------

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function formValidator(){
    // Make quick references to our fields
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');


    // Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
    if(notEmpty(username, "The username field is empty!")){
        if(notEmpty(password, "The password is empty!")){

        }
    }

    return false;

}

function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
    if(elem.value.length == 0){
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

----------------------------------------This is the form----------------------

```
<form method="post" action="loginproc.php" onsubmit="return formValidator()" >


<tr><td colspan="3"><img src="icons/login.jpg" alt="Edugate" width="366" height="123"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" nowrap bgcolor="#990033" class="infoTitle"><div align="center"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" nowrap class="infoTitle"><div align="left">user login </div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" nowrap bgcolor="#990033" class="infoTitle"><div align="center"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td width="58">Username</td>
<td width="4">:</td>
<td width="297"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" class="BtnInTable" value="Login"></td></tr>
<?php if ($error == 1)
print "<tr><td colspan='3' class='ppos'><img src='icons/error.png' alt='error'> Icorrect usename or password...</td></tr>";?>
<tr><td colspan="3" nowrap bgcolor="#990033" class="infoTitle"><div align="center"></div></td></tr>
</form>
```

---

Kindly, can anybody guide me. Thanks in advace

Comment: Your formatting is terrible.. better learn some basic HTML formatting it you ever plan to write pages that you might change sometime in the future, or that someone else will have to read/write..  have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `return true;`, it will go to `return false;` otherwise.

```
    // Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
    if(notEmpty(username, "The username field is empty!")){
        if(notEmpty(password, "The password is empty!")){
                return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it.
But can you further explain to me coz I'm sort of new to programming..

Comment: When you catch the `onsubmit` with a `return` function, that function must return true or false for your script to work. You checked the username and password if they weren't empty you did not send any return, instead there was the bottom return that was false. For the form to continue you needed to send true. As you see in your `notEmpty` they both return `false` if `elem.value.length == 0` otherwise they return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You formValidator() always returns false, and if you return false to the onsubmit, it will not submit.
Be sure to return true if everything is valid.

Answer (score 1):

heres the problem..
this function only returns FALSE.
no return true statement..
for form to submit, the "onsubmit" should return true :)

Comment: thnxxxxx so much, i understood the concept now.

Comment: No problem :). You should choose a best answer and vote up though :).